# How to set up angular project to support common navigation bar?

Tags: angularjs

There's an example given in angular [docs](http://plnkr.co/edit/5g1UjYRrXRy759yM9ls3?p=preview) which shows how to organize a project so that you can have common nav bar at the top.

Is it possible to have something similar for another app, which has no nav bar on the landing page, but then once you click on a link `/showresults/:id`, everything else should have a navigation bar? The problem I think I'm having is that `/showresults/:id` can't have ng-view? Does this require 2 modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a variable in your main page controller that doesn't exist anywhere else and then use `ng-if`

```
<main-nav ng-if="!homePageScopeVariable"><main-nav>
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that I need the `id` in `/showresults/:id` to generate the navbar...I think I need to somehow make `/showresults/:id` page act as a parent main controller

Comment: can wrap navbar in directive then and depending on router used check params in the route change success event. Use those params to determine whether to hide/show navbar